# Hangouts application (plugin) does not launch within new beta interface

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

My team develops Web service which uses Google Hangouts API.

We render Hangouts button on the page using `gapi.hangout.render` call.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-div5"></div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div5', {
    'topic': 'cats',
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'hangout_type': 'onair',
    'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
    'widget_size': 72
  });
</script>
```

Among the parameters that we pass to the function there is `initial_apps` where you can specify your application to be launched on the start of Hangouts.
Some time ago Google released the new beta version of Hangouts and now our application (plugin) does not launch within new beta interface. So our service is broken because of it.

How can we deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check first:

1. Is the button launching as a Hangout or a Hangout OnAir? Your parameters seem to suggest that it should be OnAir, but the Beta interface isn't visible in OnAir at this point. Does the button say "Start HOA" in yellow or "Start a Hangout" in green?
2. Once launched, does it appear to be the classic interface (buttons along the top and the apps listed on the left) or the beta interface (buttons along the bottom and apps are not listed at all).
3. If it does appear to be the classic interface, are the apps listed on the left, even if the app isn't running?
4. Check the console for any error messages directly related to loading your app. (There will be a number of other errors from hangouts itself.)

I was able to duplicate the problem for a while in my tests, but it suddenly started working again, so something odd may be going on.

Comment: Thank you for reply! 1) It is HOA (yellow button), but we work with Hangouts Party mode (green button) as well 2,3) The beta interface is loading, thus there are no any apps at the left side 4) Everything worked like charm before the update, but I will check again